# Codeigniter / Auto refresh page when error occurs

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am receiving the following error sometimes and I spent a lot of time to fix it but not successful. When I refresh the page it is working good.

So can I add a php command that will refresh the page whenever an error occurs?

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: unlink(/tmp/ci_session0b936e5a4c8c9cd803841162cc64af9770c7764f): Operation not permitted

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 384

Backtrace:

File: /home/univers1/public_html/app/application/controllers/Client.php
Line: 8
Function: __construct

File: /home/univers1/public_html/app/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Client.php Line: 8

```
public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("user_model");
        $this->load->model("tickets_model");
        $this->load->model("knowledge_model");
        $this->load->model("funds_model");
        $this->load->model("home_model");
        $this->load->model("FAQ_model");
        $this->template->set_error_view("error/client_error.php");
        $this->template->set_layout("layout/client_layout2.php");

        if($this->settings->info->require_login) {
            if(!$this->user->loggedin) {
                redirect(site_url("login"));
            }
            if($this->settings->info->global_premium && 
            ($this->user->info->premium_time != -1 && 
                    $this->user->info->premium_time < time()) ) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata("globalmsg", lang("success_29"));
                redirect(site_url("funds/plans"));
            }
        }
    }
```

Index.php Line: 315

```
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

Comment: whats on here`Client.php` line 8  and whts `app/index.php` ??

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I updated the question and included the related lines of Client.php and Index.php

Answer (score 0):

It is failing because `unlink` is not permitted. [unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) return true on success and false on failure. You didn't post the code in that file, but I image you can do something similar the following to catch the error.

```
$unlinkSuccess = @unlink($filepath);
if (!unlinkSuccess) {
    // Redirect
    header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $location);
}
```

That all said, it's crazy to reload a page when there's an error. If the error happens twice in a row, browsers will assume it's an infinite redirect and stop loading the page. You should figure out why unlink sometimes does not have permission. It's likely an issue with file permissions on some files or folders.

Answer (score 0):

I solved as follows. Thank you all.

```
$config[‘sess_save_path’] = NULL;
```

To

```
$config[‘sess_save_path’] = APPPATH . '/cisessions/';
```